# How do I import an SQL 3.4 database into phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I guess that my database is outdated, it was exported with a different version of phpMyAdmin, and now I'm a bit stuck because I can't figure out how to import it without errors.

This is the information of the database:

```
phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
version 3.4.11
Server version: 5.5.60
PHP Version: 5.4.45
SQL MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
```

I found out online that removing SQL MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; would do the trick, I did so for every file (since it's a big file I had to split it before importing). It works for the first one without errors, but the others keep giving me errors such as:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry for '161521' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

and

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax near '  INSERT INTO `Case` VALUES (0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0), (1010, ''
```

I tried to use the compatibility mode in the import page, but it didn't do anything, and although I searched these errors none of the solution worked, so I thought it may be because the database was exported with a different version of myphpAdmin and php, I don't know.

These are a fe lines:

```
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

INSERT INTO `Messaggie` (`IDMessage`, `IDMotherMessage`, `IDHerald`, `Title`, `Messagge`, `Author`, `IDGuild`, `Img`, `Corp`, `IDRace`, `DateMessagge`, `Read`, `Important`) VALUES
    (161521, 0, 53, '[Content] My first book', '[b]Date:[/b] 15/05/2017\r\n[b]Place:[/b] Forest\r\n[b]Characters:[/b]
```

and

```
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
                  INSERT INTO `House` VALUES         (0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),         (1010, 'House', '2010-03-24 00:00:00', 'Character', NULL, 0, 205),         (501, 'Location', '2010-03-25 00:00:00', 'Character', NULL, 10, 205),
         (401, 'ab', '2010-03-24 00:00:00', 'Character', NULL, 20, 205)
```

I noticed that   symbol in the second file, but actually it is Microsoft SQL Server that put them there since when I opened it the program told me that the line endings were not consistent and it needed to be normalized (I chose to use the Unicode Paragraph Separator, but perhpas I might change that, or not even open it there and do the editing from notepad).

Comment: can i see your sql file ?

Comment: You mean all the file?

Comment: there a lot ? if it is post few code enough to understand

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty heavy :S I'll post the codes that gives me the first errors then!
Edit: gosh I keep making mistakes hahaha just a sec

Comment: ok should be done now

Comment: You probably got error #1062, after you tried to import again your SQL data. 
Try to drop all tables after fixing errors. Second, you need to do the cleanup of all hidden ( like BOM ) and weird unicode characters.  Then try again.

Comment: I'll try to do so and I'll let you know how it went, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I'm still getting error 1064, no more 1062, but still stuck.